# How to catch first time displaying of the WizardPage

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, wizard

I'm writing a little wizard for Eclipse with some pages and I need to catch the moment of the first time page displaying.

I checked constructor and `createControl` but they are called in the creation moment in the `Wizard` object (`addPages`).

Is there a way to get what I need? Maybe somebody knows some trick?

Answer (score 4):

You can override setVisible(boolean) method in your WizardPage. So for example use something like:

```
private boolean initialized = false;

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    if (!initialized && visible) {
        //do something
        initialized = true;
    }
    control.setVisible(visible);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used another way

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `IPageChangedListener` or a `IpageChangingListener`, registered on the [WizardDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fwizard%2FWizardDialog.html). They will be notified when the current page of the wizard changes.

Comment: I don't use `WizardDialog`, I use `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard` and `org.eclipse.ui.INewWizard`. And I don't know how to use `IPageChangedListener` or `IpageChangingListener` in this case.

Comment: @user433689 use `Wizard.getContainer()` to retrieve the `WizardDialog`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to remove the listener after first painting. That way you don't need an additional boolean field and you avoid unnecessary calling paintControl and checking that boolean every time.

```
container.addPaintListener(new PaintListener()
{
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e)
    {
        doUsefulStuff();
        container.removePaintListener(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created a listener for a paint event and used a flag `m_isFirsTime`, which controlled from Wizard class:

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    setControl(container);
    container.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent arg0) {
            if (m_isFirstTime) {
                m_isFirstTime = false;
                StartXMLParsing();
            }
        }
    });
...
}
```

It is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

After controls created the async UI task executed where a long init operation can be performed. UI already created and shown when Runnable starts therefore wizard appears immediately and user can see initialization progress:

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
    // create controls
    getContainer().getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getContainer().run(false, false, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(IProgressMonitor arg0) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
                        // init and validate controls here
                    }
                });
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // handle e.getCause();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // nothing
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution!

Comment: After controls created the async UI task executed where a long init operation can be performed. UI already created and shown when Runnable starts therefore wizard appears immediatly and user can see initialization progress

Comment: I mean not for me, put this explanation into your answer to make it complete, if somebody check it he will see why your solution is working.